# WooCommerce Software Licensing Activate Remotely with C#

Tags: c#, woocommerce

I'm trying to activate a license key remotely using WooCommerce and WooCommerce Software Add-on. I'm programming in C# to do this feature and I've made the activator in PHP so all the program does is send the WebRequest to it filling in the required fields. I'm not sure why it's not activating when the program says it has sent the POST request. If I do the POST with my browser it activates the license key but through the program it doesn't do anything..

**POST request:**

```
private void SubmitData()
        {
            try
            {
                string licensekey = licensekeyTXT.Text;
                string email = emailTXT.Text;

                var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                var postData = "key=" + licensekey + "&email=" + email;
                var data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

                var request = WebRequest.Create("https://varietysplaza.xyz/rcontent/activation.php");
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.ContentLength = data.Length;

                var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                stream.Close();

                var response = request.GetResponse();
                stream = response.GetResponseStream();

                var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());

                sr.Close();
                stream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
            }
```

**Activation.php:**

```
<?php
$wp_root = "/home/varietysplaza/public_html";
if ( file_exists( $wp_root . '/wp-load.php' ) ) {
    require_once( $wp_root . "/wp-load.php" );
} else {
    exit;
}
if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) die();
include( 'productsettings.php' );
// Fire away!
function execute_request( $args ) {
    $target_url = create_url( $args );
    $data = wp_remote_get( $target_url );
    var_dump( $data['body'] );
}
// Create an url based on
function create_url( $args ) {
    global $base_url;
    $base_url = add_query_arg( 'wc-api', 'software-api', $base_url );
    return $base_url . '&' . http_build_query( $args );
}
$license_key = $_GET['key'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$args = array(
    'request'     => 'activation',
    'email'       => $email,
    'license_key' => $license_key,
    'product_id'  => $product_id,
    'secret_key'  => $secret_key,
    'instance'    => $instance
);
echo '<b>Valid activation request:</b><br />';
execute_request( $args );
```

Comment: In your php script you're not dealing with POST data, but with GET.

Comment: I don't know. It's you're the author of the script. Is it good now?

Comment: @zerkms I updated the code, it's still not activating through the web request. All it does is if put the response in a messagebox it's an empty messagebox.

Comment: Your code does not use the post request data again. Do you simply apply random changes to your code and expect it to work?

Comment: @zerkms What code are you talking about? The PHP version or C# version? If I use $_POST( on the PHP script it won't work anymore. The C# script correctly sends a post request to the website. Image: http://i.imgur.com/6lfTXBm.png

Comment: Because `$_POST(` is not valid php. "The C# script correctly sends a post request to the website" --- it surely does, but your php script does not handle the post request.

Comment: @zerkms OH alright, I see what you mean now I'm sorry. So I would use $_POST() correct and then handle the post request from C# script.

Comment: `$_POST()` it's not valid php. You are wasting your time trying to guess, seriously.

Comment: @zerkms $_POST[] is what I meant, sorry. Not sure why I put () in both comments.

Example:
$license_key = ($_POST['key']);
$email = ($_POST['email']);

Comment: @zerkms Hey I think I've figured it out, thanks for not giving me the answer (spoonfeeding) to me, I need that.

Comment: Oh, it's really great to hear that you are not angry to me after that :-D (a lot people are)